# MVC4: skip ajax success and redirect to another view from model

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a functionality where based on condition I am showing jQuery dialog box. If condition is false just need to redirect to another view with refresh reload. 
It is working fine for jQuery dialog and loading partial view.

But when condition fails I am RedirectToAction("Index") which is suppose to load fresh. But is loading again in jQuery dialog. which means Ajax call back success calling back.

my question is how to avoid jquery ajax success call back and skip completely.

here is the code.

```
 $.ajax({
        url: 'SaveAddress',
        type: 'Post',
        cache: false,
        data: $("#frmAddress").serialize(),
        success: function (data) {

            $("#dialogPopSuggestions").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 600,
                width: 500,
                modal: true,
                title: "Suggesion Addresses",
                //dialogClass: 'warning-dialog',
                open: function (event, ui) {
                    //Load the  action which will return 
                    // the partial view 
                    $(this).html(data);
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();
                }
            });
            $("#dialogPopSuggestions").dialog("open");
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert("error occured");
        }

  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveAddress(FormCollection col)
    {
           ....
           ....
            if (addresssuggestionList.Count == 0) //no suggestion
        {
            memberAddressDetails = memberAddress.AddAddress(memberId, memberAddressDetails);
        }
        else
        {
            addresssuggestionList.Add(memberAddressDetails);
            ViewBag.IsPrimaryCompany = primaryCompany;
            ViewBag.IsPrimaryAddress = mainAddress;
            return PartialView("_PopDivSuggestionAddress", addresssuggestionList); //Jquery dialog loads perfect
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");//here suppose fresh load index, not jQuery dialog.
    }
```

Comment: we send in data a param to check whether to load in dialog or not, and then based on that if we perform the redirection in success method,  it may resolve the issue..

Comment: any example, because I am sending partialview or view. those both are html data.

Comment: so basically for return view you want to refresh same page , correct ?

Comment: @Dreamweaver, no. dialog has different partialview. If I don't show dialog box. I need to redirect index (home) view.

Comment: The whole purpose of ajax calls is to stay on the same page - `return RedirectToAction("Index");` will not redirect. You need to return a value indicating you want to redirect, and then do the redirect in the success callback using `location.href="yourUrl";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function openPopup(data)
{
     $("#dialogPopSuggestions").dialog({
           autoOpen: false,
           height: 600,
           width: 500,
           modal: true,
           title: "Suggesion Addresses",
           //dialogClass: 'warning-dialog',
           open: function (event, ui) {
                //Load the  action which will return 
                // the partial view 
                $(this).html(data);
                event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();
           }
      });
      $("#dialogPopSuggestions").dialog("open");
}


$.ajax({
    url: '/Cntrllr/SaveAddress',
    type: 'Post',
    cache: false,
    data: $("#frmAddress").serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
         if(data ==null){
             location.href='/Cntrllr/Index';
         }
         else{
             openPopup(data);
         }

    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert("error occured");
        location.href='/Cntrllr/Index';
    }
```

Your controller will be

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveAddress(FormCollection col)
{   ....
    ....
    if (addresssuggestionList.Count == 0) //no suggestion
    {
        memberAddressDetails = memberAddress.AddAddress(memberId, memberAddressDetails);
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        addresssuggestionList.Add(memberAddressDetails);
        ViewBag.IsPrimaryCompany = primaryCompany;
        ViewBag.IsPrimaryAddress = mainAddress;
        return PartialView("_PopDivSuggestionAddress", addresssuggestionList); //Jquery dialog loads perfect
    }        
}
```